# MySQL Join Three Tables and Average

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I've been puzzling over how to structure a special query, and the best I can figure out is that it would have to be some kind of complex subquery system.

I'm not entirely sure, though.

I have three tables, `teams`, `matches`, and `scored`.

The `teams` table contains a list of team numbers and corresponding team names.

The `matches` table contains a list recorded match results (one row per team per match), with the corresponding team number.

The `scored` table contains a list of all of the information about each score the team made, and the corresponding match result id.

```
┌────────────┐
| TEAMS      |
├────────────┤
│ teamnumber |
│ teamname   |
└────────────┘

┌───────────────┐
| MATCHES       |
├───────────────┤
│ teamnumber    |
│ matchresultid |
└───────────────┘

┌───────────────┐
| SCORED        |
├───────────────┤
│ matchscoredid |
│ matchresultid |
└───────────────┘
```

Given a teamnumber, I need to get the average number of rows in `scored` per `matchresultid`.  How would I do that?

Comment: The more I look at this the more confused I become. What does average number of rows per matchresultid even mean? There is only one number of rows in scored per matchresultid. How do you average one number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the one element you left out that may have confused others is the actual score of the game a given team was playing against.  So basically you want one team, and through the course of the season, you want the average # points they scored...

```
select 
      t.teamnumber,
      t.teamname,
      avg( s.totalpoints ) TeamAvgPoints
   from 
      teams t
         join matches m
            on t.teamnumber = m.teamnumber
            join scored s
               on m.matchresultid = s.matchresultid
   where 
      t.teamnumber = SomeValue
```

If you want a comparison of ALL teams averages, ignore the WHERE clause and just do a group by...

```
   group by
      t.teamnumber, 
      t.teamname
```

If the scored table has multiple rows per game, then a pre-aggregate would need to be done per game to have total points first, THEN get the average... something like

```
select
      PreQuery.TeamNumber,
      PreQuery.TeamName,
      avg( ifnull( PreQuery.MatchTotalPoints, 0 ) ) AvgPerGame
   from 
      ( select 
            t.teamnumber,
            t.teamname,
            m.matchresultid,
            count(*) MatchTotalPoints
         from 
            teams t
               left join matches m
                  on t.teamnumber = m.teamnumber
                  left join scored s
                     on m.matchresultid = s.matchresultid
         where 
            t.teamnumber IN( SomeValue, AnotherValue, MoreValues, EtcValue )
         group by
            t.teamnumber,
            t.teamname,
            m.matchresultid ) PreQuery
   group by 
       PreQuery.TeamNumber,
       PreQuery.TeamName
```

In THIS version of the query, if you wanted to compare all teams, remove the inner WHERE clause for a specific team, and apply the group by to the OUTER query by teamnumber and teamname.

To get your extra qualifier for the entire list, I've changed to LEFT joins, and finished with an IFNULL() for the average...

Comment: This answer is closest, however, if a team has played no games, every resulting column is NULL.

Comment: @CMC, so I've changed to LEFT JOINs so it will still get the team, but the count of points will be null.  So then in the outer-most, I've applied IFNULL() to use zero... Give it a shot

Comment: How would I modify this so that I get fetch based on multiple team numbers?

Comment: @CMC, check the adjustment to query.  You can add multiple teams in the IN (  ) list as I've sampled, or just remove the inner WHERE clause to get ALL teams.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the number of scores or the score average? If you need the score average, you need to replace the "count" with "avg"

```
SELECT s.matchresultid, COUNT(s.matchscoredid) 
  FROM matches m INNER JOIN scored s ON m.matchresultid = s.matchresultid
 WHERE m.teamnumber = <team>
GROUP BY s.matchresultid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.matchresultid, count(*) 
FROM scored s
JOIN matches m
ON m.matchresultid = s.matchresultid
WHERE m.teamnumber = your_team_number
GROUP BY s.matchresultid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.teamname team, b.matchresultid match, COUNT(c.matchscoredid) scores 
FROM teams a, matches b, scored c 
WHERE a.teamnumber = b.teamnumber AND b.matchresultid = c.matchresultid;
```

That should return the number of scores for each team per match.